# Emoji counter in python

Tags: python, emoji

I have a pandas data frame for WhatsApp chat.
One of the columns has all messages sent by the user. Each row is a string of words and emojis.

Is there a way I can extract the emojis and count their number.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a print-out of a small example dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*****Edit*****

My fault, should have been more specific. I just posted it from my mobile.

This needs emojis installed.

```
pip install emojis
```

So here is my solution to it.

```
emoji_count = df['msg'].apply(lambda x : emojis.count(str(x)))
new_df=pd.concat([df, emoji_count.apply(pd.Series)],1)
```

I am sure there could be other efficient way to do this. But for now, this is getting my work done.